# MFC Drag into C# Drop

Tags: c#, mfc

I Have a ProjectA(MFC Dlg) include the usercontrol(Chart c#)

When i drag the item(CTreectrl) from MFC Dlg to the C# chart .

For example :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkatk.png

And the C# m_chartGantt_DragOver will be called. but crash 
"Debug Assertion failed! ... cmdtarg.cpp 43"

```
private void m_chartGantt_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
private void m_chartGantt_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
```

I don't know how to fix it ? or it can't work actually? 
Any comments will be much appreciated.

And here is MFC Code.

```
void CDropButton::OnLButtonDown( UINT nFlags, CPoint point ){
  COleDataSource *pDataSource = new COleDataSource();
  if (DoCopyData(pDataSource))
  {
      pDataSource->DoDragDrop(DROPEFFECT_COPY);
  }
  if (pDataSource)
  {
      delete pDataSource;   **// error here!!**
  }
}

BOOL CDropTreeCtrl::DoCopyData(COleDataSource *pDataSource)
{ 
    char  szText[] = _T("Here is some sample text that was copied using a COleDataSource object!");

    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE|GMEM_MOVEABLE, ::lstrlen (szText) +1);
    if (hMem != NULL)
    {
        LPSTR pData = (LPSTR) ::GlobalLock(hMem);
        ::lstrcpy (pData, szText);
        pDataSource->CacheGlobalData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

**EDIT**

If it helps, this section of code covers line 43 of cmdtarg.cpp:

```
CCmdTarget::~CCmdTarget()
{
#ifndef _AFX_NO_OLE_SUPPORT
    if (m_xDispatch.m_vtbl != 0)
        ((COleDispatchImpl*)&m_xDispatch)->Disconnect();
    ASSERT(m_dwRef <= 1);
#endif
    m_pModuleState = NULL;
}
```

Comment: What code is at the line that ASSERT, please tell us the condition that fails.

Comment: Sorry about that . A nice person and I Edited it again. Is it OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to delete the pDataSource after you have called DoDragDrop.

It is a COM object and its lifetime is only controlled by COM.

The ASSERT tells you that somebody tries to delete the object while it is in use. Verify it and look into the callstack. It is your delete!

Comment: very Thanks !! i will try to understand that !! Thanks again !! So i have to delete the pDataSource in C# chart ? or COM actually auto-delete it by himself?

Comment: COM will autodelete it, after the last reference is gone.

Comment: But MFC shows it as a memory leak. There should be some other way out.

Comment: Have you tried calling InternalRelease() of COleDataSource derived class instance? It fixed "ASSERT(m_dwRef <= 1)" for me.